# While using a custom transformer in my M.L. pipeline, getting the "missing positional argument" error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Error I am getting

```
TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df_test'
```

```
def labling_class(df, col_name):
    Op_dict = {}
    cat = df[col_name].unique()
    for val in cat:
        df_filter = df[df[col_name] == val][["C0","C1","C2","C3"]]
        avg_col = df_filter.mean(axis = 1)
        mean_overall = avg_col.mean(axis =0)
        Op_dict[val] = mean_overall
    return Op_dict

class transform_cat(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self , col_name_list):
        self.col_name_list = col_name_list
    def fit(self ,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,df,df_test):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        df_append = df.copy()
        df_append = df_append.append(df_test)
        for col_name in  self.col_name_list:
            lable_dict = labling_class(df_copy,col_name)
            replace_dict = {col_name : lable_dict}
            df_append.replace(replace_dict, inplace=True)
        return df_append

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

Data_labeling = Pipeline({
    ("cat_transform",transform_cat(["product","packing","dosage","Market_Code","packing_code"]))
})

processed_data = Data_labeling.fit_transform( X_train_master, X_test_master ) 
processed_data.shape
```

I am getting the above error for the following code. I understand that it is taking the first arguments 'X_train_master' as self and thus needs the 3rd argument. But this should not be the case.
If I change the definition of transform_cat function to

```
    class transform_cat(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self , col_name_list):
        self.col_name_list = col_name_list
    def fit(self ,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,df):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        #df_append = df.copy()
        #df_append = df_append.append(df_test)
        for col_name in  self.col_name_list:
            lable_dict = labling_class(df_copy,col_name)
            replace_dict = {col_name : lable_dict}
            df_copy.replace(replace_dict, inplace=True)
        return df_copy
```

And call it using

```
processed_data = Data_labeling.fit_transform( X_train_master)
```

It works just fine. Can some one point out what is going wrong in this case?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? Currently it can not be reproduced because for instance "X_train_master" is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
 Data_labeling.fit_transform( X_train_master, X_test_master )
```

with:

```
 Data_labeling.fit_transform( X_train_master, df_test=X_test_master )
```

Minimal explanation:

```
def bar(x, y=None, **kw):
    return foo(x, **kw)  

def foo(x, z):
    pass

>> bar(4, 6)

>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in bar
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'

>> bar(4, z=6) #runs ok
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, But even this does not seem to work. I am more interested in understanding why is it ignoring the self passed as the 1st parameter in the above case. Or is it that due to some reason the self of the object is not being passed to the method